# Some Images not being drawn on JPanel

Tags: java, image, swing

I'm writing an application in Java that retrieves the cover art of books. Most of the images that I try retrieving are displayed just fine, but periodically, I'll run into one that doesn't display and I can't for the life of me figure out why. Maybe someone can help me. Here is the relevant code:

```
private BufferedImage cover;

        try {
            cover = ImageIO.read(new URL(coverArt.getImageURLs().get(0)));
        } catch (IOException exception) {
            System.out.println("error");
        }

@Override
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        //System.out.println(buttonPanel.getHeight());
        if (LeftPanel.getCollectionTable().getSelectedRow() >= 0) {
            g.drawImage(ComicBookCollection.getComicBookCollection().get(LeftPanel.getCollectionTable().getSelectedRow() + positionAdjust).getCover(),
                    12, 80, getWidth() - 25, getHeight() - 130, null);
        } else {
            repaint();
        }
    }
```

There is a list of strings of image urls that is compiled before this. I know that the list is being compiled correctly. For some reason, it is only for specific random titles. If I put Superman 2 in there, it doesn't come up, but if I put Superman 1 in there, it does. I've tried using the url of the problematic images in other programs and they display just fine. Maybe someone can figure out what is gong on.

[image: The image is supposed to display on the right]

[image: This is what it is supposed to look like]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code looks fine, but it's non-standard so there may be some gotcha somewhere.

Try using standard Swing components for this. I.e. have the right panel be a `JLabel`, and make it show the image by wrapping it in an `ImageIcon` object and calling `setIcon` on the label.

Comment: I actually tried doing that at one point and it was doing the same thing. I also had to use the graphics to resize the image so that it would fit correctly.

Comment: Does the call to ImageIO.read return an image object or null? Try turning off the cache using ImageIO.setUseCache, see if that helps.

Comment: Could you explain what that does? I'm a bit new to graphics and stuff.

Comment: ImageIO caches the images, so that it does not have to go to the web each time you call it. This gives a great performance boost, but if the image is corrupted, you'll keep getting the corrupter image. Turn the cache off, and see if that works. If ti does, you'll need to detect this condition in the program so you can display an error message to the user or force the cache to refresh.

Comment: Interesting. I just did a system.out.print on the image and it returned null. I tried disabling the cache but it didn't do anything. Where should I put that line of code? It's possible that I didn't put it in the right place.

Comment: If it returned null, it means that the image is not readable by ImageIO. What's the image type?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/132064/discussion-between-michael-bar-sinai-and-namarino).